# Robot/Crawler Dection in ASP.NET <browserCaps> vs .browser

Tags: asp.net, browser, cross-browser

I implement search engine dedection using the  element in conjunction with the mammoth list provided by Owen Brady: http://owenbrady.net/browsercaps/CodeProject.xml

I see no reason to change to use .browser files instead of using browserCaps. Are there any reasons why I should do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the main advantage is that .browser files can be amended on the fly whilst updates to the browserCaps section of your config file will cause an application reset.